# Python 3.4.2 AND pip Permission Issues

Tags: python, pip

I've been struggling with an issue with Python and pip installs (python version 3.4.2, same with x86 or x64 MSIs, Windows 7 x64). I'm using the CPython installer available from the Python.org website.

When I install, I get the UAC prompt, which I approve, and it installs fine to `D:\opt\python34` (along with pip, as added in 3.4.2 installations by default). Then, as standard procedure, I add the install path and Scripts subfolder to the user path variable. Now, the issues are as follows:

1. Whenever I run `python setup.py install` inside any package directory, the prompt hangs at `writing ... to top_level.txt` or `writing to dependency_links.txt` or etc. (Same issue happens if I create a virtual environment using python -m venv, activate it, and do python setup.py install). Setup.py never succeeds. Pip install  also hangs infinitely after giving a warning "manifest_maker: Standard file '-c' not found."
2. If I remove setuptools, and just use distribute, then "python setup.py install" works.

Kindly assist with ideas/solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of trying a workaround, I finally got down to debugging the setup.py script and setuptools and distutils. Figured out the problem was a missing "svn.exe" on my workstation, which caused the "svn_finder" function in setuptools core to hang up.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can make the right team aware of the "bug"?